# How can I use Google Vision OCR On-Premise?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I need to use Vision API to OCR sensitive documents (passeports/IDs...). But Google Cloud doesn't seem to meet GDPR requirements and I'd prefer hosting the models on our servers.

Vision OCR On-prem exists (https://cloud.google.com/vision/on-prem) but I can't find any other information on how to install or use it. Only the pricing.

Has anyone ever done this before ? Is there any public documentation ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can read about Vision API's data usage here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage  What are you concerned about in regards to GDPR? Google doesn't retain your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to jump through the hoops of working with Google's sales team for the on-prem vision solution, but you don't have an ML background to train/retrain your own model, you might consider [Google AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl). This would allow you to retrain a model with minimal effort - all in their web-based console - and the results would be downloadable and able to run on various platforms such as mobile (TFLITE) or in the browser (TFJS).

Comment: but is that possible to install and run in local/own servers? because i dont want to upload sensitive data to cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Vision API's data usage here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage Note that Vision API doesn't retain your data.

If you still want to use Vision API OCR onprem anyway, you would have to contact sales: https://cloud.google.com/contact